# How do I add text if there's no content in my div?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I add text to an empty list? If there's nothing added I want to have my own text.
Do I need to add `v-if`, `.length` or?

```js
  .row.pl-3.pr-3.this-row
    .col-md-8
      p.title Name
    //- .col-md-4
    //-   p.title Banned products
  .row.py-2.pl-3.pr-3.disrow.d-flex.align-items-center(
    v-for="disease in dietDiseases"
  )
    .col-md-6
      span {{ disease.name }}
    .col-md-6.text-right
      b-button(variant="danger", @click="deleteDietDiseases(disease.id)") Delete
```

Comment: You could do `{{ disease.name || "Default text" }}`

Comment: This isn't working. I do not see the text if I didn't add any disease.

Comment: It should work, could you add more of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `v-if` condition just before your `v-for` element:

```js
.row( v-if="dietDiseases.length === 0" )
  span My custom text
.row(
  v-for="disease in dietDiseases"
)
  ...
```

Note that you should not add a `v-else` to the `v-for` component, since the `v-for` will not display content if the array is empty. You can run into unexpected issues if you use `v-if/else` and `v-for` on the same element. Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

**EDIT:** If the `v-for` row should not be rendered for styling reasons, you can place it inside a `<template>` tag which [acts as an invisible wrapper](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt):

```
.row( v-if="dietDiseases.length === 0" )
  span My custom text
template( v-else )
  .row(
    v-for="disease in dietDiseases"
  )
    ...
```